# Use of scalar functions in Join condition

Tags: sql-server, performance, join, user-defined-functions

I am joining with a table to retrieve a value but in order to join I need to do some logic because both the tables do not have a common value in place. So the logic is to do a top 1 and get a certain value from a common table for both the inputs. I am planning to put the logic inside a scalar function and then call it in the join condition.

I have a simple join as something like this

```
LEFT JOIN <IndexTable> Tbl1 ON Tbl1.PrimaryKey = MainTbl.PrimaryKey
```

I intend to change this into something like this using a user defined scalar function

```
LEFT JOIN <IndexTable> Tbl1 
ON dbo.fnGetCommonID(Tbl1.PrimaryKey) = dbo.fnGetCommonID(MainTbl.PrimaryKey)
```

In terms of performance is it good to use it this way or is there any better way for this.

Comment: The optimizer won't be able to use any index in the `ON` condition of the join in the version with scalar functions.  The first version is preferable, assuming it's possible to phrase your query that way.

Comment: Could I recommend you post the scalar function? There is possibly someone who can help achieve the same result efficiently...

Comment: create persistent computed column on both table and join on the computed column

Answer (score 0):

If possible, do your calculation inside the query, maybe using an OUTER APPLY instead of a LEFT JOIN:

```
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 <at least one field, also values from MainTbl may be used>
    FROM <the set of data you need>
    WHERE <boolean, also values from MainTbl may be used>
    ORDER BY <make the top record the one you want>
) AS Tbl1
```